# Bootstrap Single Toggle Button (implemented as Button Element) -- How to Get Selection

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntmv4Luq/2/

I have a single Bootstrap Toggle button which works in the On/Off mode. I need to get the current selection/value to make decisions, but the value is always blank.

One other thing, I'm noticing the button never gets de-toggled.

```
<button id="buttonToggle" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Toggle</button>

    $('#buttonToggle').click(function() {
            alert('Clicked, value = ' + $(this).val());
        });
```

I sort of understand that Val() doesn't work on a button, but I only have one element. Do I really need to use radiobuttons or checkboxes styled as a button?

Comment: You should refresh your knowledge of Bootstrap 4s "Toggle State" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#toggle-states as the code you've written will not, and cannot, accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#buttonToggle').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('activated');
      alert('Clicked, value = ' + $(this).hasClass('activated'));
      if($(this).hasClass('activated')){
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something else
      }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ec1hduy7/1

Comment: Works. BTW the JSFiddle link pointed to mine, yours is: https://jsfiddle.net/ec1hduy7/1/

Comment: Fixed. I forked the JSFiddle from the one you posted in your question and forgot to change the URL. XD.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to find if the current button is  active class or not

```
$('#buttonToggle').click(function() {
            alert('Clicked, value = ' + $(this).attr("class"));
            console.log( $(this).hasClass("active") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#buttonToggle').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('aria-pressed') ? true : false;
        alert('Clicked, value = ' + value);
    });
```

Comment: thanks; the button always stays "true" for "pressed" after the 1st click, though